# Copy SKB to USART DMA

Tags: c, network-programming, driver, device, usart

Hello i am writing a network device driver. I already setup the USART.
i registrated the Network device in the Probe funktion like this:

```
my_net = alloc_etherdev(sizeof(struct stm32_port));
    if (my_net == NULL){
        return ENOMEM;
    }

    /* Set MAC address */
    eth_hw_addr_random(my_net);
    
    my_net -> netdev_ops = &my_net_ops;
    
    SET_NETDEV_DEV(my_net, &pdev->dev);    
    
    return register_netdev(my_net);
```

now in the ndo_start_xmit methode my kernal always gets a panic when i try to copy the socked puffer to the CPU dma adress

```
    static int my_net_send(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *ndev)
{
    //struct stm32_port *priv = netdev_priv(ndev);
    //unsigned int entry = TX_BUF_L;
    //unsigned int entry = tp->cur_tx;

    struct stm32_port *lp = netdev_priv(ndev);
    struct sk_buff *sk_buff;
    unsigned pktlen = skb->len;


    /* adjust the packet length to min. required
     * and hope that the buffer is large enough
     * to provide some random data.
     */
    if (pktlen < ETH_ZLEN)
    {
        if (skb_padto(skb, ETH_ZLEN))
            return NETDEV_TX_OK;
    pktlen = ETH_ZLEN;
    }
    
    //pr_info("do_start_xmit(skb=%p, ndev=%p) len=%u\n", skb, ndev, pktlen);

    netif_stop_queue(ndev);
    //send 
    if (lp->tx_dma_busy)
        return NETDEV_TX_BUSY;
    
    //pr_info("copy to usart: %s", skb->data);
    sk_buff = skb_get(skb);
    pr_info("copy to usart: %s", sk_buff->data);
    memcpy(&lp->tx_buf[0], sk_buff, pktlen);
    //dma_addr_t dma_addr = dma_map_single(ndev->d, skb->data, skb->len, DMA_TO_DEVICE);
    
    ndev->stats.tx_packets++;
    ndev->stats.tx_bytes += pktlen;
    dev_kfree_skb (skb);
    netif_start_queue(ndev);
    return NETDEV_TX_OK;
}

struct stm32_port {
    struct uart_port port;
    struct clk *clk;
    struct stm32_usart_info *info;
    struct dma_chan *rx_ch;  /* dma rx channel            */
    dma_addr_t rx_dma_buf;   /* dma rx buffer bus address */
    unsigned char *rx_buf;   /* dma rx buffer cpu address */
    struct dma_chan *tx_ch;  /* dma tx channel            */
    dma_addr_t tx_dma_buf;   /* dma tx buffer bus address */
    unsigned char *tx_buf;   /* dma tx buffer cpu address */
    u32 cr1_irq;         /* USART_CR1_RXNEIE or RTOIE */
    u32 cr3_irq;         /* USART_CR3_RXFTIE */
    int last_res;
    bool tx_dma_busy;    /* dma tx busy               */
    bool hw_flow_control;
    bool fifoen;
    int wakeirq;
    int rdr_mask;       /* receive data register mask */
    struct mctrl_gpios *gpios; /* modem control gpios */
};
```

Whats the correct way to copy the socked puffer. Sorry i am new to device drivers.

Comment: Why are you doing `skb_data = skb_put(skb, pktlen);` ? If I remember correctly, `skb_put` moves the `data` field in the `sk_buff`. This would cause an out of bounds access .

Comment: For reference - https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/networking/API-skb-put.html

Comment: You are also printing the packet contents with `pr_info`. Are the packet contents guaranteed to be terminated with a `\0`?

Comment: sorry it was wrong i tried to make a copy of the socked buffer with skb_get before i copy it. the pr_info was just for me to look at it.

Comment: Okay, now with the change it should be `memcpy(..., skb_buff->data,...)` (like you have in the `pr_info`. Can you actually include the code that you are trying to compile/run so we can identify the error correctly?

Comment: i tried bouth already before but always with the same result my system crashes.

Comment: at least now its not crashing anymore i wrote it now like that memcpy(&lp->tx_buf, sk_buff->data, pktlen);

Comment: With the changes does it show the right behavior? Are your tx buffers getting the appropriate packet contents?

Comment: no it does not send the packages over the usart. but at least my kernel does not crash anymore. But so far i have at the moment no idea what to change so it will send it.

Comment: My problem was not in the send methode it was my initialisation of the usart.